# IntelliJ: All Haxe compile conditionals treated as false

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe

I posted this on the [InjelliJ Haxe plugin's git issues](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/intellij-haxe/issues/725) already, but I'm not sure if this is an actual bug or if I'm supposed to do something so the editor... knows the values or something

in the below example debug is true, and the same thing happens to **#if flash** or any other #if, meanwhile every **#if !foo** has active syntax coloring.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbkCa.png
(I don't have permission to post images yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the active compiler flags by editing the "Project Macros" found under:

- `File` -> `Project Structure`
- `Project Settings` -> `Modules` -> `your-haxe-mod-name`
- `Haxe Tab` -> `Edit Button` next to `Project Macros`

[image]

The defines also show up in the `.idea/haxe.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes my issues. But is there any way to have these auto-populated from my openfl project xml's haxedefs?

Comment: Doesn't seem like the current release supports auto population.

Comment: If IntelliJ used `openfl display` (like the Visual Studio Code extension does) then it would know many of the defines that are available

Comment: I got a response on the git issue I linked. It appears it's already in progress. Feel free to bring up VSCode's implementation to him if you think it will help.